# Cauchy–Schwarz inequality in complex variables

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, complex-numbers, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have seen various proofs for Cauchy–Schwarz inequality but all of them discuss only of real numbers. Can someone please give the proof for it using complex numbers in simple steps?

Comment: Have you seen the proof on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Proof)?

Comment: I am new to this, wikipedia is tough for me to comprehend.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have prove C-S for real numbers, here is a way to prove the complex case. Giving $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$, you want to prove that $$|\langle x,y \rangle| \leq \|x\|\|y\|$$ The problem is that $\langle x,y \rangle$ is not real. Consider $u =\frac{\overline{\langle x,y \rangle}}{|\langle x,y \rangle|}$ It is clear that $\langle ux,y \rangle$ is now real. Hence by real C_S, you get $$|\langle ux,y \rangle| \leq \|ux\|\|y\|.$$ But $|u|=1$, hence you get the desired inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$, and $x$ and $y$ elements of an inner product space.  Then, if $z=x-\lambda y$ we have

$$\begin{align}
||z||^2&=\langle x-\lambda y,x-\lambda y\rangle\\\\
&=||x||^2+|\lambda|^2||y||^2-2\text{Re}\left(\lambda \langle x, y\rangle\right) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

At the minimum value of $||z||^2$ with respect to $\lambda$ we must have both

$$\frac{d||z||^2}{d\text{Re}(\lambda)}=0 \tag 2$$

and

$$\frac{d||z||^2}{d\text{Im}(\lambda)}=0 \tag 3$$

From $(2)$ and $(3)$, we find that

$$\lambda=\frac{\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}}{||y||^2} \tag 4$$

Substituting $(4)$ into $(1)$ reveals that the minimum of $||z||^2$ with respect to $\lambda$ is

$$\min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{C}}\left(||z||^2\right)=||x||^2-\frac{|\langle x,y\rangle|}{||y||^2} \tag 5$$

Inasmuch as $||z||$ is the norm of $z$, it must be non-negative for all values of $\lambda$, including the value of $\lambda$ that minimizes $z$.  Therefore, from $(5)$ we obtain the coveted Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{|\langle x,y\rangle|\le ||x||^2\,||y||^2}$$

with equality if and only if $z=x-\lambda y=0$, or equivalently $x=\lambda y$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Syomantak, please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.If the answer was not useful, then I am happy to delete it. -Mark